# How can I initialize variables at runtime using the matlab coder?

Tags: c++, matlab, initialization, runtime, matlab-coder

I have a function that I export with the matlab coder to C++ code. In the code a matrix is loaded from a mat file. I was using:

```
coder.load('filename.mat');
```

However this does not allow me to change the file at runtime.

I tried a solution by first saving the file as a binary using `fwrite` and then reading as follows:

```
fileId = fopen(filename_variable,'r');
file_data = fread(fileId,Inf,'double');
fclose(fileId);
```

This allows me to load different files at runtime. The function however is called at 5Hz and is thus continuously loading the file in this case. Is there a way to only load the file once in Matlab? Or is there another approach to solve this problem?

**PS:**
To pass the filename to the Matlab side I use in Matlab:

```
coder.typeof('s',Inf);
```

and pass a variable of type `emxArray_char_T` to the matlab function, create by:

```
emxArray_char_T* filename = emxCreateWrapper_char_T(filename_char_pointer, 1, size);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `persistent` variable in MATLAB to just read the data on the first call to your function. This assumes that the data in the file would never change from call to call.

```matlab
function y = foo(...)
persistent file_data;
if isempty(file_data)
    % This only runs on the first call to foo
    fileId = fopen(filename_variable,'r');
    file_data = fread(fileId,Inf,'double');
    fclose(fileId);
end
use(file_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `fread` function to the c++ code. Although this is not really what I wanted to do.